# How do I use the detrending function for matplotlib.pyplot.acorr?

Tags: python, matplotlib, autocorrelation

I am a Python beginner. I am trying to detrend a time-series before running an autocorrelation analysis by using acorr in matplotlib. But there is something about the syntax that I fail understand.

Matplotlib's website (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.acorr.html) describes how to use detrending with the acorr function: "x is detrended by the detrend callable. This must be a function x = detrend(x) accepting and returning an numpy.array." I must be reading this wrong, because the code I use does not work.

## Failed attempts:

```
plt.acorr(values, detrend=True)
plt.acorr(values, detrend="linear")
plt.acorr(values=detrend(values))
```

As you can see, some rudimentary fact about syntax or matplotlib escapes me. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In [matplotlib.mlab](https://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.detrend) you find functions which you can use for detrending. An example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import mlab

wn = np.random.normal(size=10**3)

plt.figure()
plt.acorr(np.abs(wn), maxlags=200, detrend=mlab.detrend_none) #default detrend

plt.figure()
plt.acorr(np.abs(wn), maxlags=200, detrend=mlab.detrend) #subtract sample mean
```